# TFS get specific version of solution

Tags: tfs, version-control

Is there any trick to just get a specific version of *just* a solution?  I have a large number of solutions and support libraries in the source code tree.  I would prefer not to have to bring all of them down when I build a sandbox of a specific labelled version. In VS2015, I can open a specific solution, but is there a way to specify the label when I do this?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to choose the version of the solution when opening it.

You can however choose to get a specific version of the solution and its projects when getting the source code locally. You can do this by right clicking the solution folder in the *Source Control Explorer* and selecting *Get Specific Version*. Here you can select a specific version either by specifying a changeset, label or date.

Comment: So you're saying that if you already have the solution in your sandbox, you can pull down another labelled version?  But first you need to pull down the entire tree?

Comment: Basically you choose what you want locally. Usually that would be *latest*, but in special cases you could choose to get a specific version. If you want to do actual changes to this specific version, then you might use a branch to do so.

Comment: I get the part where I can bring down a version of any individual leaf in the directory tree, but that process is prone to error with a large, interdependent set of solutions and support libraries.  I was looking for a fail-safe way to create a sandbox with Solution A - Label Beta 1.2 in one sandbox and Solution B - Label Release 4.2 in another.  It sounds to me like you're saying I have to pull down the entire tree for both sandboxes and then I can pick the labelled version I want.

Comment: Yes, I don't see any other way as the solution is 'just' a collector of projects and files without any source control version information.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution with the suggestion from Tore.  You can use the **File/Source Control/Advanced/Open From Server...** to load the latest version of a solution into your sandbox.  Once you have the latest, you can use Tore's suggestion of Right Clicking on the solution then **Source Control/Get Specific Version...** to pull down the labelled version you want to work on.  This appears to limit the file structure of the sandbox to just the files you need to build the solution.

Seems to work with the limited number of labelled version I have.  Will update this post if I have trouble with more history in the vault.